# Can I index a body word\index{body word} without having to write "body word" 2x?

Tags: imakeidx

I'm making my first index. The MWE below writes the word "once" to the index but not to the body. So, I need to write `once\index{once}` if I want the text in the body and the index. I can write a macro to do this for me, so can write `\myindex{once} and have it appear in the body and the index. Is there a built-in LaTeX way to do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

1. This is how you use the index command\index{command}.\\
2. Instead of typing "command" twice above, I'd rather
type it \index{once}.\\

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand\foo[1]{#1\index{#1}}` ... `\foo{command}`

Comment: Indexing is generally going to be for concepts and categories (`cat\index{carnivores, domestic}` type of thing) and takes as much effort as composing the main text. So a macro for text indexing (word or phrase) seems best.